# Unable to locate frame? Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Ruby and Selenium and I thought I had switching to frames to locate an element in the bag but looks like I don't.

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchFrameError: Unable to locate frame: 1

or

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError
```

But there is an iframe within the html that is wrapped around the element that I am trying to find. I used the Selenium recorder to better figure out which frame this is and it tells me the index is 1. I have tried locating the frame by its id but it is unable to locate it. I then tried to wait for 20-60 seconds in hopes that would somehow work. It just times out.

The only difference that I could see between the other times I have switched frames and now is that the frame I am looking for now is within a loop. Does that affect it at all? Any help is appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
select_list.options.each { |option|
             if option.text == ""
                @driver.find_element(xpath: '//*[@id="txt_source"]/option[2]').click

                @driver.find_element(xpath: '//*[@id="search_button"]/button[2]').click #small arrow

                sleep(10)

                @driver.find_element(xpath: '//*[@id="search_button"]/div/a[3]').click #Button that navigates to the next page


                sleep(10)
                @driver.find_element(xpath: '//*[@id="main_action"]').click




                @driver.switch_to.frame(1) #Where is fails




                @driver.find_element(xpath: '/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input').click

               @driver.switch_to.default_content


             end

        }
```

Comment: Hi Use WATIR which is a wrapper for Ruby Selenium Binding. And ask questions by tagging watir , more people will come on your help.

Comment: Except this isn't watir code, and Watir takes a distinctly different approach to iframe management.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch into a frame as part of a loop, you need to switch back out of it or the second iteration of the loop won't work.

```
@driver.switch_to.default_content
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I have tried doing this previously and now I get a new error. At this point it might be wiser to just try to use Capybara or Watir.

Comment: Oh, I missed that you were navigating to a new page. You can't iterate through a list of elements while navigating away from those elements.

Comment: No way.
But I have successfully chosen an option, went to a different page, and went back -- albeit I'm getting the stalevalue error when I return but I got through it the first time...now I'm trying to figure out how to go down the list...You could be right - I don't know what I'm doing.